# Wishing to end a while: loop with break

Tags: python

```
    nc = dict(zip(nation,cap)) 
    print("Countries and Capitals :{}".format(nc))
    
    k = 0
    while k != 5:
        k = input("input : ")
        if k == 1:
            break
        if k != 1:
            key = k
            print("The capital of {} is {} ".format(key,nc[key]))
```

#This only makes an error when I type in 1. I want it to stop the program when pressed 1. What can I do about it?

Comment: Welcome to SO.   ```k = input("input : ")``` has ```k``` being a string.  Try ```if k == "1":``` and ```if k!= "1":```.

Comment: ```if k == "1"``` instead of ```if k == 1:```, Because when you use ```k = input``` the `k` variable will be in ```str``` object.

Comment: @dungxibo123 just realized that the poster also compares in the while loop ```k != 5``` so I'm guessing it'd be more 'efficient' (for lack of a better word) to just do ```k = int(input("input : "))```

Answer (score 0):

`input("input ")` returns a string.

You could do:

```
nc = dict(zip(nation,cap)) 
    print("Countries and Capitals :{}".format(nc))
    
    k = 0
    while k != 5:
        k = int(input("input : "))
        if k == 1:
            break
        if k != 1:
            key = k
            print("The capital of {} is {} ".format(key,nc[key]))
```

Answer (score 0):

`input()` returns string by default.
So,
You need to take **k** as integer input using `int()` function.

```
k = int(input("input..."))
```